# multiple websites/domain multiple public ip vs multiple websites one public ip

Tags: iis-7, hosting, subdomain

My current setup right now is to have 1 Public IP and 1 Domain per country Hosted in my IIS in RACKSPACE, we have 5 countries right now and thinking of launching 2 more but we are running out of Public IP's so i thought  is there more efficient and cost effective ways to this?

ex. www.mywebsite.sg, www.mywebsite.nz, www.mywebsite.hk

I'm thinking of just using 1 Public IP and 1 Domain but wouldn't it be too much of a strain in my IIS if i only have 1 Public IP?

ex. www.mywebsite.com/sg, www.mywebsite.com/nz, www.mywebsite.com/hk

Answer (score 0):

This is done in just about any web platform using "Virtual Hosts". The general idea behind the technology is that any requests coming in on (for example) port `80` from anywhere with the http header that matches your site name (this is filled from the URL - the address bar) are then redirected to a dedicated docroot for that site rather then the "default". IIS calls these "bindings" rather than "virtual hosts", but it's the same thing.

This way, we can use multiple sites with the same IP. Their domain names can be whatever you want them to be, so your scheme of alternating only TLD within DNS will work fine. The following link will help with specifics:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site

Regarding stress, that's up to you to test. You can run a massive amount of sites from one IIS server if the server is provisioned correctly. Look closely at your resource usage and fit in what you can, but try to not 1:1 provision an edge web server - they're prone to be hit hard when fortunate sharing of your site comes around.